# use for loop for mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

My first code was this

```
$it= mysql_query("SELECT comp_specs.type FROM comp_specs INNER JOIN users ON comp_specs.id=users.specification_id WHERE users.workgroup_id=1 AND comp_specs.type=0", $connection);
 $it_num =mysql_num_rows($it);
 $arrastre= mysql_query("SELECT comp_specs.type FROM comp_specs INNER JOIN users ON comp_specs.id=users.specification_id WHERE users.workgroup_id=2 AND comp_specs.type=0", $connection);
 $arrastre_num =mysql_num_rows($arrastre);
 $clinic= mysql_query("SELECT comp_specs.type FROM comp_specs INNER JOIN users ON comp_specs.id=users.specification_id WHERE users.workgroup_id=3 AND comp_specs.type=0", $connection);
 $clinic_num =mysql_num_rows($clinic);
 $Admin= mysql_query("SELECT comp_specs.type FROM comp_specs INNER JOIN users ON comp_specs.id=users.specification_id WHERE users.workgroup_id=4 AND comp_specs.type=0", $connection);
 $Admin_num =mysql_num_rows($Admin);
```

and this work great, but it took me lots of line code, so i tried doing this

```
$field=array('$it', '$arrastre', '$clinic',  '$admin' );

foreach($field as $fields){
 $(fields)= mysql_query("SELECT comp_specs.type FROM comp_specs INNER JOIN users ON comp_specs.id=users.specification_id WHERE users.workgroup_id=1 AND comp_specs.type=0", $connection);
 $(fields)_num =mysql_num_rows($fields);
}
```

but an error happen.

I need some help on how to use foreach loop to query multiple times

Comment: "*..but an error happen.*" What Is That **ERROR**?

Comment: Replace `$(fields)= mysql_query("` with `$fields= mysql_query("S`

Comment: And, Replace `$(fields)_num =mysql_num_rows($fields);` with `$fields."_num" =mysql_num_rows($fields);`

Comment: when i tried to display my query... it said undefined variable

Comment: we are not allowed to use ( or ) i.e. brackets in variable declaration. Avoid using such special symbols in variables.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help...

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove brackets from`$(fields)` to `$fields` and stop using `mysql_*` because it doesn't exists anymore in PHP 7

> Depending on the version of PHP, there are either two or three PHP
>   APIs for accessing the MySQL database. PHP 5 users can choose between
>   the deprecated mysql extension, mysqli, or PDO_MySQL. PHP 7 removes
>   the mysql extension, leaving only the latter two options.

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.php)

Answer (score -1):

while use for this procedure

```
$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
```